# Query nested complex json structure with Apache Drill

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill

I have a json file with many json object like this one

```
{
"created_time": "2015-04-15T15:12:43+0000",
"updated_time": "2015-04-15T15:12:43+0000",
"comments": {
    "data": [
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T18:09:06+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 4,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Ana Paula Mandlaze Gomez",
                "id": "1413157615397359"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981613971858482",
            "message": "\"Many people, especially ignorant people, want to punish you for speaking the truth, for being correct, for being you. Never apologize for being correct, or for being years ahead of your time. If you' re right and you know it, speak your mind. Even if you are a minority  of one, the truth is still the truth.\"Gandhi"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T16:33:27+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 2,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Ana Paula Mandlaze Gomez",
                "id": "1413157615397359"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981574091862470",
            "message": "I love I love GHANDI"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-22T19:47:59+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Fardous Alhorafi",
                "id": "1800049323548924"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_985418828144663",
            "message": "كان عبقري"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T21:06:35+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Jamal Abdulrahman",
                "id": "1366198393416315"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981681661851713",
            "message": "This great leader"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T15:35:42+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Sergio Pellicciotta",
                "id": "1307515282677785"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981548471865032",
            "message": "ci vuole la pazienza"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T16:31:44+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Merve Tacirli",
                "id": "773109599535260"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981573545195858",
            "message": "Key word: patient"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-08-15T21:36:38+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Tu Abuela",
                "id": "10212662776625548"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_1046913331995212",
            "message": ":)"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T19:38:53+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Vikash Tiwari",
                "id": "977320485738496"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981645241855355",
            "message": "sadar naman bapu"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T15:29:21+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Nikunj Patel",
                "id": "1370944359688528"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981545948531951",
            "message": "Aaapko khiladi ka salaaM"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-16T06:01:33+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Satya Prakash",
                "id": "791386747691183"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981861258500420",
            "message": "......patience es depth of laef.."
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-27T20:46:37+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Javier Arce",
                "id": "1353955594657881"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_988593714493841",
            "message": "COMIC - THE DAY GANDHI DIE - COMIC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g7KpUx0qSQ"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "2015-04-15T15:28:59+0000",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false,
            "from": {
                "name": "Nikunj Patel",
                "id": "1370944359688528"
            },
            "id": "981539778532568_981545825198630",
            "message": "Bhai"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {"cursors": {
        "before": "MTYZD",
        "after": "MQZDZD"
    }}
},
"status_type": "added_photos",
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/FatherofNation/photos/a.279218472098039.73934.173835512636336/981539778532568/?type=3",
"icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/photo.gif",
"is_hidden": false,
"privacy": {
    "allow": "",
    "deny": "",
    "description": "",
    "value": "",
    "friends": ""
},
"message": "You cannot achieve durable reform by becoming impatient. - Mahatma Gandhi",
"type": "photo",
"object_id": "981539778532568",
"picture": "https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/10300287_981539778532568_5512778811597106826_n.jpg?oh=900c8f181224cef2b2b93688a0ef9d88&oe=599C0E7D&__gda__=1508137453_7f9508a338248a38665e21299f8410bb",
"shares": {"count": 140},
"is_expired": false,
"name": "Timeline Photos",
"from": {
    "name": "Mahatma Gandhi",
    "id": "173835512636336",
    "category": "Public Figure"
},
"id": "173835512636336_981539778532568",
"likes": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Rai Santi",
            "id": "699214820279365"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rabari Bhavesh Bhandu",
            "id": "197158197474003"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cristiano Hussaini",
            "id": "469179660091433"
        },
        {
            "name": "D Pák Ský",
            "id": "342182466199173"
        },
        {
            "name": "Joseph Muendo",
            "id": "893394437480382"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kati Vali",
            "id": "10209489431495182"
        },
        {
            "name": "Neelam Gupta",
            "id": "278625325934685"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rahul Patel",
            "id": "298644327257948"
        },
        {
            "name": "Niti Jani",
            "id": "1520081698036960"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sara Maria Crespo Echeandía",
            "id": "10155452589526055"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sonia Quintana Castillo",
            "id": "485471615125223"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tello Maweng",
            "id": "720777431451520"
        },
        {
            "name": "David Figueroa",
            "id": "1886084661665963"
        },
        {
            "name": "Aphle Grace Celestre Devera",
            "id": "1517425511643699"
        },
        {
            "name": "Angel Legaspi Alquizar",
            "id": "327218104364636"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sanjeev Mishra",
            "id": "1207468336065542"
        },
        {
            "name": "Patricia Fastinger",
            "id": "1956586287688483"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bojana Simonovska",
            "id": "10155588604414614"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nath Schmidt",
            "id": "1337540319645871"
        },
        {
            "name": "Santoshi Nallanchakravartula",
            "id": "1364678026914798"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pabitra Kumar",
            "id": "631689807038744"
        },
        {
            "name": "Thaís Araujo",
            "id": "1350769495004631"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dilip Singh Rathore",
            "id": "1711441295817067"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kamlesh Saini",
            "id": "1987451464817042"
        },
        {
            "name": "SaDhu Ka",
            "id": "1490063764348943"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/173835512636336_981539778532568/likes?access_token=166536670200421%7Cb8948bb3c57f35a94afee5d5869854b7&limit=25&after=MTQ5MDA2Mzc2NDM0ODk0MwZDZD",
        "cursors": {
            "before": "Njk5MjE0ODIwMjc5MzY1",
            "after": "MTQ5MDA2Mzc2NDM0ODk0MwZDZD"
        }
    }
}}
```

I want to make an SQL query using apache drill to access nested object eg comments.data[0].message. I tried every thing and followed the official guide for querying complex JSON data but did't work.

> select comments.data[0].message FROM dfs.`/home/dhaker/Desktop/GhandiOffcialPage/Facebookposts.json`

this is the error from jdbc:

> VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 8 to line 1, column 15: Table 'comments' not found

SQL Query null

[Error Id: c50f3051-79f8-4f35-b9bd-fd51c06ecb61 on dhaker-X550V:31010]
[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put an alias for the path and then call like this :

> select posts.comments.data[0].message FROM dfs./home/dhaker/Desktop/GhandiOffcialPage/Facebookposts.json posts;

it works fine like that.